# Prueba automatizada con Selenium usando netbeans produce Cannot find firefox binary in PATH

Tags: java, java-8, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Estoy tratando de reproducir la página del facebook con selenium utilizando NEtbeans java. pero me sale este error al hacer el  Test File.

> OpenPagen caused an ERROR: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make
>   sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LinuxBuild info: version:
>   '3.12.0 ...(246 chars omitted).

Aquí el codigo y las dependencias del pom.xml

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TransaccioIT {    

@Test
public void OpenPages(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String url = "http://www.facebook.com/";

    driver.get(url);
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta descargar el controlador que utiliza Selenium para controlar a Firefox. El controlador lo puedes descargar desde aquí.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Descarga el archivo zip y descomprimelo. Recuerda la ruta donde lo guardaste, la necesitaras mas adelante.

En tu código Java antes de crear una instancia de `FirefoxDriver` tienes que configurar la propiedad del sistema con la ruta del controlador.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\Users\USER\Downloads");
```

> La ruta no tiene que incluir al controlador en si, si no la ruta de la carpeta que lo contiene.

En este caso el binario estaría almacenado en la carpeta Downloads.

Referencia:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/#selenium

Comment: en sus dependencias yo veo selenium-firefox-driver, además de que en su error veo que dice que tiene linux